# Error converting Dask to pandas df in function

Tags: python, bigdata, dask

## **Context:**

I am trying to compare 2 very large datasets. The datasets should be identical in structure since one of the datasets is an updated version of the previous dataset. Any data structure changes should be caught in code I have written to check for data structure changes.
The file I am working with can be downloaded using: https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_December_2023.zip

The comparison should result in the identification of new rows, deleted rows, and updated rows. Those changes are defined as follows:

- **New**: New 'NPI' codes are codes found in the most recent update (December 2023) but are not codes found in the previous update (November 2023). NPI is the column that holds what I consider the primary key.
- **Deleted**: Deleted 'NPI' codes are codes not found in the most recent update (December 2023) but exist in the previous update (November 2023).
- **Updated**: Updated 'NPI' codes exist in both datasets however, there is at least one difference in value in the columns I most care about.

I am using Dask instead of pandas to read the data because reading with pandas requires chunking the data which takes way too long and tends to freeze up my laptop due to low memory.
I am also limiting the datasets to the select columns I most care about.

After created the Dask DataFrames, I am using those data frames in a function I created to compare the files. The code below does not contain the Updated Rows logic because I first wanted to get the New and Deleted changes working first.

## **Problem**

The problem occurs when executing my function called compare_ddf.
*ValueError: Mismatched types found in pd.read_csv/pd_read_table.*
It shows me Columns that I had not included in my read logic as the error exceptions. I am not sure why these are still remaining after the read logic.

## **My code**

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask import delayed
import time

# subset of columns required.. in form of dictionary to limit and eventually load into PG DB table.
column_name_mapping = json.load(open('column_name_mapping.json', 'r')) 
csv2db_col_dict = {v:k for k,v in column_name_mapping.items()}

nov_df = dd.read_csv('npidata_pfile_20050523-20231112.csv',usecols = csv2db_col_dict,
                     dtype={'NPI': str, 
                            "Provider Business Practice Location Address Telephone Number": str,
                           "Entity Type Code": str,
                           "Provider Business Mailing Address Postal Code": str,
                           "Provider Business Practice Location Address Postal Code": str,
                           "Provider Business Practice Location Address Fax Number": str})


dec_df = dd.read_csv('npidata_pfile_20050523-20231210.csv',usecols = csv2db_col_dict,
                     dtype={'NPI': str, 
                            "Provider Business Practice Location Address Telephone Number": str,
                           "Entity Type Code": str,
                           "Provider Business Mailing Address Postal Code": str,
                           "Provider Business Practice Location Address Postal Code": str,
                           "Provider Business Practice Location Address Fax Number": str})

#renaming these columns because they will eventually go into a postgresql db table 
nov_df = nov_df.rename(columns=csv2db_col_dict)
dec_df = dec_df.rename(columns=csv2db_col_dict)

def compare_ddf(cms_df, dec_df):
    start = time.time() #tracking/logging load time
    npi = 'npi'
    
    # convert dask df's to pandas df's
    df_old = nov_df.compute()
    df_new = dec_df.comput()
    
    # create dictionaries to store rows based on npi
    old_dict = dict(zip(df_old['npi'],df_old.to_dict(orient='records')))
    new_dict = dict(zip(new_dict['npi'],new_dict.to_dict(orient='records')))
    
    # New rows
    new_rows = [row for _, row in df_new.iterrows() if row['npi'] not in old_dict]
    if new_rows:
        logging.info(f'New rows found: {len(new_rows)}')
        for row in new_rows:
            logging.info(f'New: NPI {row[npi]}, Values: {row}')
    
    # Deleted rows
    deleted_rows = [row for _, row in df_old.iterrows() if row['npi'] not in new_dict]
    if deleted_rows:
        logging.info(f'Deleted rows found: {len(deleted_rows)}')
        for row in deleted_rows:
            logging.info(f'Deleted: NPI {row[npi]}, Values: {row}')
    
    end = time.time() - start
    logging.info(f'Comparison duration: {end}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    compare_ddf(nov_df,dec_df)
```

- Also note that although I spell out the data types for a subset of columns, they do not persist once the dataframes are loaded.

For this task in general I've tried reading the files with pandas chunk size = 1000000 and reading to a data frame using a for loop. This took a while to complete which might be okay since this process will be triggered once a month and work in the background. For testing purposes, I need something faster to test with and that won't kill my Jupyter notebook kernel.

Comment: I'm wondering, if it is easier to implement with relational engine. Two bulk inserts, add indexes by `npi`, then query differences. btw `iterrows` might be a bottleneck here.